# Finish multiple activities on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android application with multiple activities:

I have 3 activities **A1**, **A2**, **A3** that will be called from an activity **X0** like this:
**X0** -> **A1** -> **A2** -> **A3**

**X0** can be any other activity of my app, so I don't have access to it's type.
On activity **A3** I have a button that need to finish **A1**, **A2** and **A3** and go back to **X0**.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can consider using fragment instead of Activity (since the UX are similar)

Comment: Like having a fragment inside X0 that contain A1 then A2 then A3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a working solution, but it's very unclean I guess:

When I start my activity **A1** inside the activity **X0**, I give the type of the activity **X0** as a string (using flag).

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(A1));
newActivity.PutExtra("endActivity", typeof(X0).Name);
StartActivity(newActivity);
```

On activity **A1**, I get the flag like this:

```
string endActivityType = Intent.GetStringExtra("endActivity");
```

Then when I start the activity **A2** and **A3** I keep giving the type of **X0** as a string using flag:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(A2));
newActivity.PutExtra("endActivity", endActivityType);
StartActivity(newActivity);
```

And once I want to go back to **X0** inside my activity **A3**, I do:

```
 Type typeX0 = Type.GetType("MyAppNamespace." + endActivityType);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeX0);
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
 StartActivity(intent);
```

as Kashish said.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Activity X0 is already in th back stack, you can do the following -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A3.this, X0.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

With the addition of flags, all the activities on the top of Activity X0 will be closed and X0 will become visible and it won't restart too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! The flags helped me, but my problem was mostly how to get X0.class since it can be multiple activities

Answer (score 0):

Setting these flags should do the trick when you are working on the last activity (A3) in this case. 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Alternatively, you can use fragments which will allow you to transition directly from A3 -> X0 without having to finish A1 or A2.